# Any tips for structuring C++ code using win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, code-structure

I am trying to improve my coding skills by making my code more structured and readable. I code the GUI (thanks edit). I have been reading through Firefox's open source code to improve but it uses GTK+ and not much Win32.

Where can I find an open source (professional) program that is coded in Win32?

One more thing: When should one write pseudocode? I've never done this before, but I know it's much like outlining an essay. Should pseudocode be written before coding the project? or just functions?

Thanks

Comment: pseudo code is a different question, you should ask it apart

Answer (score 2):

Instead of learning Win32 API, I recommend that you learn how to use portable toolkits and libraries that will run on all major desktop platforms. In particular, check out:

- C++ standard library: strings, file I/O, containers, algorithms
- [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries: Smart pointers, network I/O, signals/slots, multithreading, filesystem, serialization, and many more.
- [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/): Portable GUI toolkit.

These libraries have higher-level APIs that are much more pleasant (IMO) to use than the bare Win32 API.

To "outline" your programs, (especially object-oriented style programs) check out the [Unified Modeling Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language).

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode is usually used to express ideas to people who use different languages. It appears really often in scientific papers (helps to understand solutions, algorithms and so on)

Answer (score 0):

As a Unix programmer I can't help much with the Windoze question.

As for pseudocode, think of it as a way of getting your thoughts together, much as you might write an outline of a letter or an essay before the real thing. I like to do it if there is any complexity to work out because I find that the compiling and debugging are easier. However, you know yourself better than I do ...

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the chrome source which is both Win32 (and now also Linux) and c++. I learned a lot from it.

PS: When you write Win32, what is your exact interrest? GUI? System calls?